# How to visualize categorical frequency difference

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

**Data**: Diabetes dataset found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LahiruTjay/Machine-Learning-With-Python/master/datasets/diabetes.csv

**Objective**: I want to examine how many people under the Age of 30 have diabetes, which is indicated by a 1 or 0 in the "Outcome" column of the dataset and plot it to see if there is a class imbalance (more of 1 or more of 2 or roughly equal?)

**Method**:

1. Filter my dataset as such:

```
ages_under30 = data.loc[data.Age < 30].loc[:,["Age"]]
outcome_under30 = data.loc[data.Age < 30].loc[:,["Outcome"]]
```

*This **successfully** returns all of the ages under 30 and what the person's outcome is (0 or 1).*

2. I want to plot the points to see if what the class representation looks like. Are there certain ages that are more diabetic? X-axis would be "ages_under30" and y-axis would be "outcome_under30".

```
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Diabetic?")
plt.plot(age_under30, outcome_under30, "o")
```

[image]

See figure above. This is where I need help. You cant really make heads or tails of this. There is a class imbalance in this age group - infact 312 samples are not-diabetic while only 84 are. How can I adjust the plot to better depict this class imbalance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The difference in `'Outcome'` for each `'Age'` can most easily be seen with a bar plot showing the count, which can be done directly with a `seaborn.countplot`, or calculating the counts in pandas, and plotting with `pandas.DataFrmame.plot`.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Data and Imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LahiruTjay/Machine-Learning-With-Python/master/datasets/diabetes.csv')

# filter for less than 30
u30 = df[df.Age.lt(30)]
```

### Use [`seaborn.coutplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

- Directly show the counts of observations in each categorical bin using bars.
- This can also be down with [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and `kind='count'`, which creates a figure-level plot

```py
sns.countplot(data=u30, x='Age', hue='Outcome')
```

[image]

### Use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- Use `.crosstab` to compute a frequency table between `'Age'` and `'Outcome'`.

  - This can also be done with groupby, but then the dataframe requires further manipulation for plotting.

```py
# reshape the dataframe
ct = pd.crosstab(u30.Age, u30.Outcome)

# plot
ct.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

[image]

### Data

- Incase the data at the GitHub link is no longer available

```py
Age,Outcome
21,0
26,1
29,0
27,0
29,1
22,0
28,1
22,0
28,0
27,1
26,0
25,1
29,0
22,0
24,0
22,0
26,0
21,0
22,0
21,0
24,0
25,0
27,0
28,1
26,0
23,0
22,0
22,0
27,0
26,1
24,0
22,0
22,0
22,0
27,0
26,0
24,0
21,0
21,0
24,0
22,0
23,0
22,0
21,0
24,0
27,0
21,0
27,0
25,0
24,1
24,1
23,0
25,0
25,0
22,0
21,0
25,1
24,0
23,0
23,1
26,1
23,0
26,0
21,0
22,0
29,0
28,0
22,0
23,0
21,0
22,0
24,0
23,0
21,0
23,0
22,0
27,0
21,0
22,0
29,0
29,0
29,1
25,0
23,0
26,1
23,0
21,0
27,0
25,1
21,0
29,1
21,0
23,1
26,1
29,1
21,0
28,0
27,0
27,0
21,0
25,0
24,0
24,1
25,1
21,1
26,0
22,0
26,0
24,1
24,0
22,1
22,0
29,0
23,0
26,1
23,1
27,0
21,0
22,0
22,1
29,0
23,0
23,0
27,0
24,0
25,0
21,1
25,0
24,0
27,1
24,0
25,1
24,0
21,0
28,1
21,0
21,0
25,0
29,1
23,0
22,0
28,1
29,1
26,0
21,0
25,1
24,1
28,0
29,1
24,0
25,1
28,1
29,0
21,0
25,1
22,0
27,1
25,0
26,0
29,1
28,0
25,1
21,0
24,0
23,1
25,0
22,0
26,0
22,0
22,0
22,0
23,0
26,0
29,0
24,0
21,0
28,1
29,1
29,1
29,1
21,0
22,0
25,1
21,0
21,0
25,0
28,0
22,0
22,0
24,0
22,0
21,0
25,0
25,0
24,0
28,0
27,1
21,0
25,0
22,1
25,0
25,1
26,0
25,0
28,1
28,0
25,0
22,0
21,0
21,1
22,1
22,0
27,0
28,1
26,0
21,0
21,0
21,0
25,0
26,0
23,0
22,0
29,0
29,1
28,0
21,0
22,0
24,0
25,1
28,0
26,0
22,1
26,0
23,0
23,1
25,0
24,0
24,0
26,0
21,0
22,0
25,0
27,0
28,0
22,0
22,0
24,0
29,1
29,0
28,0
23,0
24,1
21,0
28,0
24,0
22,0
25,0
21,0
28,0
21,0
21,0
21,0
22,0
24,0
28,1
25,0
26,0
26,0
24,0
21,0
21,0
24,0
22,0
22,0
24,0
29,0
24,0
23,1
23,0
27,1
25,0
29,0
28,0
21,0
25,0
23,0
28,0
28,1
24,0
27,0
22,0
21,0
21,0
22,0
22,0
23,0
25,0
21,1
21,1
27,0
22,0
29,0
25,0
24,0
25,0
22,1
21,0
26,0
24,0
28,0
21,0
22,1
25,0
27,0
23,0
24,0
26,0
27,0
23,0
24,1
28,0
28,0
21,0
21,0
29,0
21,0
21,0
21,0
24,0
23,0
22,0
23,0
28,0
27,0
24,0
27,0
22,1
23,0
23,0
27,0
28,0
27,0
22,0
25,1
22,0
27,1
22,1
24,0
21,0
22,0
25,0
25,1
23,0
22,0
26,1
22,0
27,1
25,0
22,0
29,0
23,0
23,0
25,0
22,0
28,0
26,0
26,0
27,0
28,0
22,0
23,1
24,0
21,0
24,0
21,0
25,0
22,0
22,0
22,0
22,1
24,1
22,0
28,0
21,0
21,0
26,0
22,0
27,1
22,1
28,0
25,0
26,1
26,0
22,0
27,0
23,0
```

Comment: It's answers like these that make programming such a joy to learn. Mr. Trenton McKinney: I hope you know how grateful I am for your post. I took a deep dive and learned "crosstab", ."Lt" (much cooler than using "<"), dataframe.plot. 

Thank you.